# LibGDX creating ModelInstance after create() has ended

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Ok, I'm making a monopoly-like game where in the game-loop activity I have a fragment with a LibGDX inside, which represents the 3D board with pieces. I've been struggling in the last few days figuring out how can I create additional `ModelInstances` after the activity has loaded and the `create()` method in the LibGDX class has ended. Here is the Demo3D.java holding the board and pieces:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    pieces = new ArrayList<ModelInstance>();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.position.set(0f, 1.6f, -4f);
    camera.lookAt(0f, 0f, 0f);
    camera.near = 0.01f;
    camera.far = 12f;

    mapTexture = new Texture("monopoly_board.jpg");
    mapSprite = new Sprite(mapTexture, 1024, 1024);

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    modelBuilder= new ModelBuilder();

    board = new Board3D(mapSprite, mapSprite);
    board.worldTransform.rotate(Vector3.X, 270);
    board.worldTransform.rotate(Vector3.Z, 180);
    board.worldTransform.translate(0, 0, 0);


    createPiece("blue");
    createPiece("green");


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    modelBatch.render(board);
    for (ModelInstance piece: pieces) {
        modelBatch.render(piece, environment);
    }
    modelBatch.end();
}

// Some other methods...


    public void createPiece(String pieceColor){
// Some logic...

    ModelInstance mi = new ModelInstance(modelBuilder.createCone(0.2f, 0.4f, 0.2f, 20,
            pieceMat,
            VertexAttributes.Usage.Position|VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal), -1.95f, 0.1f, -2.2f);
    pieces.add(mi);
    render();
}
```

So I basically need to be able to call a method from the activity/model which would result in invoking
    `createPiece(String color)` in the Demo3D class, resulting in a new piece shown on the board.

I tested calling the `createPiece()` from the outside and it creates a new piece and shows it but the board disappears. I tried calling `render()` at the end of `createPiece()` and in this case the board doesn't disappear but the newly created piece is not present... Couldn't dig anything up so I'd be glad if someone helps..
Cheers

So I decided to make a button "Start" which when pressed gets all the players and creates pieces for every player. This is the Listener:

```
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.populate)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boardFragment.populatePieces(currentGame.getPlayers());
            rollDice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Where the `boardFragment.populatePieces(Arrl<Players>)` is:

```
for (Player p: players){
        instance.createPiece(p.getTokenColor());
    }
```

The odd thing is that yesterday I decided to test this out without any changes and in Genymotion it runs perfectly, adding and removing pieces with no problems at all /Running HTC One X in Geny/. But just few hours ago I decided to test it out on my physical device and there it is the problem again... My device is Huawei Mate 7 with Lolipop 5.1

Update: It turns out the app doesn't work properly on Lollipop devices haven't tested it out on physical devices with Android 4/6, but in Genymotion everything is smooth with 4/6 devices..

Comment: Could you share the code where you call your `createPiece(String color)` method outside? And did you debug to find out why your board disappears?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make sure that in your **drawScene()** method, you iterate over the **pieces** collection and draw/render each component.